# Select and Options Styling

Tags: html, css, html-select

How to style the select options?  I want alternating background colors in the drop down menu.

Comment: Or Swing? Tkinter? wxWidgets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like any other element

```
option:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

option:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

If you need to support browsers that don't support `nth-child` you'll need to use a class.

Some browsers don't support styling `option`s at all (guess which ones).

Comment: thanks a lot.  how to limit the number of the items displayed ?

Comment: Not possible. That's up to the browser or even the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if this is going the way of HTML/CSS, I might as well suggest a wonderful jQuery UI plugin called [UI Selectmenu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/). It is the most wonderful thing I have seen about select menus so far. I bet you could easily implement alternating option colors with it.

But it's fair to say that this plugin is in development stage - proceed with caution!

Answer (score 0):

Just add size attribute along with select tag. Example select size="4", where 4 is the no of options to be displayed.