# Styling portion of Select Option text

Tags: html, css, html-select

I am looking for a way to style Option text within a Select dropdown. I came across [several stack articles such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101135/select-and-options-styling) but I can't seem to get them to work. I'm testing in Safari. Is that the problem? Below is a sample of some basic code I threw together. All that it produces - as far as I can see - is a standard, select dropdown with unformatted options. I also tried applying classes to the options, but this didn't seem to have any effect either.

```
<select name="1"><option value="1">default</option><option value="2" style="color:#0D0">green line</option><option value="3" style="background-color:red">red background</option><option value="4" style="text-decoration:line-through">line through</option></select>
```

My end goal, is to be able to style the options as follows:

```
<option value="1"><span style="text-decoration:line-through">$Regular Price</span><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">$Sale Price</span></option>
```

Comment: Is anyone else having this problem with Safari?  I'm using Safari 6.0.2.

Answer (score -1):

try to see this one? http://jsfiddle.net/Vainglory07/pzHqT/

```
  <select name="1">
     <option value="1">$Regular Price</option>
     <option>$Sale Price</option>
  </select>​

  option:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: red;
  }

  option:nth-child(odd) {
     background-color: blue;
  }​
```

id use the link youve provided..the answer there is working,isnt it?

Comment: It doesn't work on mine...just looks like a normal, un-styled select drop down.  Perhaps it's a Safari issue?

Comment: maybe yes..read this article [link](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/)..

Comment: As far as I can tell, nth-child works in Safari...but no matter what I do, the Select Options won't take any style!